# PHP DOMElement get attribute value with php shorttag

Tags: php, dom

I have a document in phtml that has this tag:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?= getenv("LANDING_DESCRIPTION") ?>">
```

And I want to use the `DOMDocument()` library to read the content attribute of that, but I believe that is because php shorttag echo, I get only `<?= getenv` has value of content attribute.

Any clue ?

Comment: Did you check `getenv("LANDING_DESCRIPTION")` is not empty?

Comment: If you want the page to have the various components filled in (i.e. the actual value of `getenv("LANDING_DESCRIPTION")`) you will need to request it as a web page rather than reading the source file.

Comment: this is actually a file that i need to check if that enviroment variable is in meta tag in tests